# Distribute $30$ marks to $8$ problems

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> In How many ways can $30$ marks be assigned to $8$ problems such that each question has at least $2$ marks?

I solved it by finding the coefficient of $x^{30}$ in $(x^2+x^3\dots)^8$ which turned out to be $\binom{21}7$

But this assumes that the arrangement say $"9,3,3,3,3,3,3,3"$ is same as $"3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3"$

What if the questions are numbered (i.e. the above listed two cases are not the same). How to proceed in that case? I don't think I can just multiply by $8!$ because of various repetition of marks.

Comment: It does *not* assume the arrangements you mention are the same. Your answer is correct.

Comment: So you are asking: "what if such arrangements are looked at as the same?" Do I understand you correct now? If so then I do not understand the word "multiply" and would rather expect "divide".

Answer (score 1):

If the questions are numbered, consider $$\sum_{i=1}^8 (x_i+2) = 30$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^8 x_i = 14$$

where $x_i \ge 0$.

We can then use a [star and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) method to solve the problem.

Comment: The OP already found that answer, so I wonder what his real question is.

Comment: if the order doesn't matter, perhaps a relevant keyword is [partition function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html)